# complex filter in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, filter

I have a list of products I am displaying and I am currently working on a filtering function that does not use ajax.

Every product has a series of classes attached to it based on a category it falls under. So like this:

```
<li class="f_all f_cat1 f_cat2">Product 1</li>
<li class="f_all f_cat1 f_cat3 f_cat_4">Product 2</li>
<li class="f_all f_cat4 f_cat5 f_cat6">Product 3</li>
```

This means that many products fall under the same category.

These are the filter options:

```
<table cellspacing="10">
  <tr>
    <td class="item" id="p_1">Category 1</td>
    <td class="item" id="p_2">Category 2</td>
    <td class="item" id="p_3">Category 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have a basic filter working so far, that allows me to filter based on a single category, that looks like this:

```
function filterProd(filter){
$(".f_all").hide(); // first hide all products
$(".f_"+filter).show();  // show products only for this category
}
```

Then the click function:

```
$("#p_1").click(function(){filterProd("cat1");});
$("#p_2").click(function(){filterProd("cat2");});
$("#p_3").click(function(){filterProd("cat3");});
```

I know that this is not the ideal way to do this but i'm just looking for a little guidance.

I am trying to achieve 2 things after this:

When the option is clicked AGAIN, remove that filter from the function

When another option is clicked, ADD it to the filter

I am assuming a function of sorts that accepts an array of values etc, but i'm fairly new to jquery and would appreciate any help i can get at this point.

Comment: I have just edited this as i realised i had made a couple of mistakes which may of made the question slightly confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to store the filters in an array: http://jsfiddle.net/4yWWH/

EDIT: modified to show all products and exit if there are no filters: http://jsfiddle.net/4yWWH/1/

Comment: This is almost perfect! Thank you very much for this. It is a little buggy and unfortunately i know too little to try and debug it. For example if you click category 1, then click it a second time, it removes all products. I kind of understand why it does this, but as i said, it's beyond my skillset just yet. Any suggestions?

Comment: the second time you click category 1 it is removed from the filter, therefore there are no items in the filters array. Check the update to the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need something like a global variable to list all the currently filtered options. So I'm going to suggest an array, but this may or may not be what is best for you. To all the naysayers going "booo, global variables suck" I ask you to evaluate the expertness of the user here and consider the option in keeping with the usability of the answer.

```
var options = { 'cat1':false,'cat2':true,'cat3':false,'cat4':false,'cat5':false} //you can figure this out on your own.
function GetFilterValues(){
  var returnFilter = '';
  for(key in options) {
    if (options[key]) { //this checks to see if the value is true
      returnFilter = returnFilter + '.f_' + key + ' ,';
    }
  }
  //remove the last comma
  if (returnFilter.substring(returnFilter.length - 1) == ',') returnFilter = returnFilter.substring( 0, returnFilter.length - 1 );
  return returnFilter;
}
```

and then just use this function in your selector like so:

```
function filterProd(filter){
  $(".f_all").hide(); // first hide all products
  $(GetFilterValues()).show();  // show only selected categories.
}
```

For adding and removing a filter option from the list, try this:

```
function toggleOptionsValue(key){
  options[key] = !options[key];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I am following you.

Just now wondering about the actual click event. So at the moment if i have a div like this:

`<div id="p_1">Category 1</div>`

.. and i wish to fire the filter when this is clicked, how would I tell that global variable that this parameter is now true.

This what i had:

`$("#p_1").click(function(){filterProd("cat_1");});`

Comment: @dangermark do you want to make it true or do you want to flip the state?